# Set ContentTemplate for ListViewItem from Custom View

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, view

I create custom View for ListView control.

```
public class CustomView: View{
//...
        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; }
//...
}


<CustomView x:Key="Custom">
    <CustomView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CustomView.ItemTemplate>
</CustomView>
```

In style for `ListViewItem` I would like bind `DataTemplate` from `CustomView.ItemTemplate` on `ContentTemplate`.

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type CustomView}, ResourceId=CustomViewItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">

    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
            Value="{Binding Path=View.ItemTemplate, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="ItemBorder">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type CustomView}, ResourceId=CustomView}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListView}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">

</Style>
```

View works but in output window in VS I get this error:

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListView',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=View.ItemTemplate;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'ContentTemplate' (type 'DataTemplate')

Comment: `I create custom View for ListView control` - why are you doing that? subclassing WPF UI elements is discouraged unless you have a `strong` reason...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
  static CustomListView()
  {        
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomListView), new 
    FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomListView)));
  }

  protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
  {
      return new CustomListViewItem();
  }
}
```